# What projection system is used in China which is aligned with WGS84

Tags: gps, coordinate-system, china

I have some GPS tracks in Beijing. I want to project it and convert the lat long degree values in meters for calculation in euclidian space. I was wondering what is the most suitable coordinate and projection system  China uses that closely resembles WGS 84 (should be one that is geocentric, I guess)?

Comment: I have coordinates from a Chinese device. The coordinates seem to be geographical Latitude and Longitude but the datum is not WGS84 (shift of several hundred meter). So, i am trying to find an answer for a similar issue, too.

Comment: In all likelihood this is related to http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141542/ and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/59931/ In which case the problem isn't that you can't find the correct projection/coordinate system, but your coordinates are actually shifted and would require a spatial adjustment to correct.

Comment: @ChrisW I think that this question asks which is the best projection for doing distance calculations, rather than the shift in the GPS data

Comment: Could you elaborate on what aspects of WGS84 should be "closely resembled"? It is unclear what you are looking for because WGS is not a "projection system" at all.

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe That's possible. I made the comment because 1) it's referenced from another question about the shift with the context of a 'China specific' system (which is how I found it), 2) the question title asks about what CRS is used in China 'aligned with' or 'resembles' WGS84, implying (to me anyway) they have GPS points in WGS84 which aren't lining up correctly, 3) the first comment also mentions a shift with apparent GPS coordinates. From both it's difficult to tell if the issue is incorrect/choice of CRS/datum, or if the actual data is in error.

Comment: @ChrisW: I completely agree that this question is ambiguous, and hence it's best that this question has been put on hold for being unclear.