# Is it possible to put a raster layer on a shifted Chinese basemap using leaflet API?

Tags: raster, leaflet, coordinate-system, china

Recently, we want to develop an application with leafleat and gaode basemap because some features of these products fullfill our basic needs. We want to overlay some raster layers caculated by spatial models by the means of adding Tilelayer or imageOverlay.

However, the trouble is that many basemaps including gaode Map have positions shifted (encoded with GCJ-02 ) in the China area. And other basemaps which do not have shifted encoding such as OSM lose many street details in the same region.

The question is how to overlay a raster (WGS84) onto an shifted basemap in leaflet?

Comment: Related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141542/ You'd need to find a correct transformation between the two datums and apply it to your rasters. A quick Google search turned up https://github.com/googollee/eviltransform but there were a lot of other results.

Comment: Thanks. I have found some algorhithms to convert a coordinate from WGS-84 to GCJ adding some offsets. But I am confused how to correct a raster image on a shifted map. China has encrpted the GCJ-02 datum so maybe there is not a easy projection.