# Are there EPSG codes for solving China GPS shift problem?

Tags: proj, epsg, pyproj, china

I am currently using [PyProj](http://jswhit.github.io/pyproj/) for a project, and would like to transform from WGS-84 (or other systems) to the [China-specific datums](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141542/what-causes-the-gps-offset-shift-in-china) for writing into kml files. I have seen [other packages](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/eviltransform/1.0.0) specifically for fixing the China projection problem, but would rather use PyProj if possible.

Are there an EPSG codes for the BD-09 or GCJ-02 datums? I was unable to find any. Alternately, is there any other way to transform WGS-84 to GCJ-02 or BD-09 using PyProj?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of 30 March 2017, no, there are no coordinate reference system, nor transformations for BD-09 or GCJ-02 in the EPSG Registry. As far as I'm aware as a member of the subcommittee that maintains the registry, no request has been made to add either one.

A big issue with a request is getting reliable information as part of the request even of the geographic coordinate reference systems themselves.

It would highly unlikely that EPSG would add any transformations because that information is controlled by the Chinese government. Why would the government want that information in a public repository?

I looked at two online solutions that purported to handle the CGJ-02 offset. Neither one worked particularly well. The offsets are not regular in a way that lends itself to an easy solution as well.